# File download script not working after changing from WAMP server to LAMP server.

Tags: php, download, lamp

I moved my application from a WAMP server (PHP version <= 5.2, Windows XP) to a LAMP server (PHP > 5.3, Ubuntu 12.04 LTS), and the problem that I have now is that my download function outputs the file on the screen and it's not forcing the browser to perform a download.

Anyone can point me in the right direction?

Here's the code:

```
function download()
{

$fullPath = $_POST['fisier'];

if($fullPath=="NULL")
{
 echo "Wrong path!";
}
else
{

$fd = fopen ($fullPath, "r");

if ($fd) {
    $fsize = filesize($fullPath);
    $path_parts = pathinfo($fullPath);
    $ext = strtolower($path_parts["extension"]);    

    switch ($ext) {
        case "pdf":
            header("Content-type: application/pdf"); 
            break;

        case "tiff":
            header("Content-type: image/tiff");

            break;

        case "tif":
            header("Content-type: image/tiff" );
            break;

        default:    
             header("Content-type: application/force-download");
            break;
    }
    header("Content-Description: File Transfer"); 
    header('Content-Disposition:  attachment; filename="'.$path_parts["basename"].'"');
    header("Content-length: ".$fsize);
    header("Cache-control: private"); //use this to open files directly


    ob_clean();
    flush(); 
    while(!feof($fd)) {
        $buffer = fread($fd, 2048);
        echo $buffer;
    }

}

fclose ($fd);
exit;
}
}
```

Comment: `header("Cache-control:..)` is used to specify the cache behaviour of the browser, not open file directly. Moreover, why are you using `ob_clean()` ? Finally, you can simplify your code with `file_get_contents` to retrieve the content of the file and then echo it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `Content-Disposition` header as per the [PHP docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php):

> If you want the user to be prompted to save the data you are sending,
>   such as a generated PDF file, you can use the » Content-Disposition
>   header to supply a recommended filename and force the browser to
>   display the save dialog.

```
// It will be called downloaded.pdf
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="downloaded.pdf"');
```

Answer (score 0):

try using `header("Content-type: application/octet-stream");` instead of `header("Content-type: application/force-download");`

Answer (score 0):

> The recommended action for an implementation that receives an
>   "application/octet-stream" entity is to simply offer to put the data
>   in a file

From [here](http://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2046.txt). Looks like your `application/force-download` is non standard.